# What are some examples of "service activities" for the inexperienced/up-and-coming academic?

Tags: job-search, service-activities

I am looking for an assistant professor job in engineering. While working on my Ph.D., I had the chance to mentor graduate students in my research group (suggesting experiments, helping them analyze results, etc.), and I also mentored an independent studies student for a summer. Would these types of activities even loosely be considered as "service activities" by a search committee, or, if the question comes up during an interview, just say that I don't have any such activities to mention? If the latter, what are some good ways to respond?

Comment: I believe mentoring graduate students is not service; it is a standard component of being a postdoc or professor. However, you should include it on your CV under a section called something like "students mentored" and then list their names.

Comment: @MHH: Thanks for the suggestion of including "students mentored" on my CV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the question in the title, some common examples would be organising a seminar, helping to organise a conference or workshop, or serving on a committee.

I don't think that the activities you mention are generally considered 'service'.  They are definitely activities worth mentioning in other contexts, though.

If you really don't have any experience in 'service activities', then perhaps a good way to respond to questions about service would be to admit that you don't have such experience so far, but express interest in gaining such experience (with specific details of the kinds of service you are especially interested in).  I have no idea whether this is good advice, though, as I'm only a postdoc myself and have never been on a search committee.

Answer (score 4):

As a grad student, you're not expected to devote much time to professional service.  Even assistant professors are usually intentionally spared time-intensive service roles.  Expectations increase as you become more senior.  I was never asked about service in an interview for a post-doc position, and your postdoctoral supervisor would probably rather hear that you don't have time for service because you spend all your time on research.

I think the only service activity you should naturally expect to be involved in is that of refereeing papers, but that generally won't happen until you have one or more accepted publications.

You might also organize a minisymposium at a conference -- that's considered service and is a great excuse to get to know researchers in your subfield.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is specific to the US, but on many graduate school admissions, search, or internal program related committees, there will be a graduate student representative serving alongside professors. I have seen people put this as service.

You can also volunteer to preside at conferences, organize sessions, or serve on journal editorial boards, review as an ad-hoc reviewer if you have opportunities to do so.

Another way of showing general commitment to the field and scholarship, at least in the humanities and social sciences, is contributing book reviews for journals (or other publications with book review sections). This will not go under the "service" section of your CV, but under a separate "book review" heading and will be a nice way of showing commitment to the field.

However, I have also heard warnings against overdoing these things, especially when you do not have a good enough publication record. It can be seen as proof of inefficient time management, and not having one's priorities straight. As book reviews are not peer reviewed, and easy to get, they can be seen as "fluff" to your CV, if you have too many with not much else going on.

Answer (score 2):

As a current graduate student there are 3 primary ways in which I provide service to the academic community and mention them on my cv.

1. Reviewing articles in journals and conferences. I regularly review for a top journal in information science and a couple of the top conferences in HCI (Human Computer Interaction)
2. I am the student member on our department's PhD admissions committee. My responsibilities include evaluating prospective applicants with the rest of the committee, matching applicants with interviewers and organizing the PhD visit day.
3. I have been a student volunteer for top conferences in my area. Some of my other colleagues have been student volunteer chairs for said conferences or they have been in the organizing committee for such conferences.

These are only my personal services to the academic field and my department recognizes and honors these services as an integral part of being a scholar (teaching-research-service).